# Where is "Unpublish App" button in new Google Play developer console interface?

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

In old google play developer console interface, "unpublish app" button used to be at top right corner. It is not there anymore. I can't find it in release management section either. Google help pages are also outdated they point me to the old version location "top right corner".
So does anyone know where can i find it now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After exploring every section of developer console I found it in "Price & distribution" section's subsection "App Availability". Hope it save someone else's time.